# Detect URLs changes in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I need to detect urls changes when shops have a firesale on, I'm using requests lib with no luck even when a firesale is on it still returns `No deals on today` and check value is still `[u'http:', u'', u'www.dealwebsite.co', u'Electroshop']`

primary shop url 
    `http://www.dealwebsite.com/coolshop`

if firesale deals are on the primary shop url changes to this like a redirect
    `http://www.dealwebsite.com/coolshop/firesale`

```
import requests

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit\/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome\/45.0.2454.101 Safari\/537.36'
}

select_shop = 'Electroshop'

url = 'http://www.dealwebsite.co/' + select_shop
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=3)

check = r.url.split('/')

if len(check) != 5:
    print 'No deals on today'
    exit()
else:
    print 'Firesale Deals on NOW!'
```

Comment: What is the value of `check`?

Comment: check = `[u'http:', u'', u'www.dealwebsite.co', u'Electroshop']`

Comment: What is the expected output for such a query? Also, why can't you check r.status_code for response code and r.text() or r.json() for result data? r.url gives you the request URL and tells nothing of the response provided by the server.

Comment: I tryed r.status_code and still responses with 200 when no firesale is on, plus some shops will use random firesale string like `1lPvoW3xb` I just want a true or false statement that its on or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can [track redirection](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history).  For example:

```
requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=3, allows_redirect=True)
>>> r.url
'url'

>>> r.status_code
200

>>> r.history
[<Response [301]>] # means that there was a redirect on the way
```

Actually, you could use just a HEAD request to verify the behavior - only if you don't need to parse the result (as a HEAD response body is empty).

```
>>> r = requests.head(url, headers=headers, timeout=3, allow_redirects=True)

>>> r.url
'..something...'

>>> r.history
[<Response [301]>]
```

In theory, you could also prevent the redirect completely, and check for the response status.

```
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=3, allow_redirects=False)

>>> r.status_code
301

>>> r.history
[]
```

Now, 301 might mean a redirect to firesale or somewhere else - you don't know.

**UPDATE 1**

An example with periscope.tv (it seems that the OP has issues with such a website):

```
>>> example = requests.get("https://periscope.tv/couchmode", allow_redirects=True)
>>> example.status_code
200
>>> example.history
[<Response [307]>]
>>> example.history[0].url
u'https://periscope.tv/couchmode'
>>> example.url
u'https://periscope.tv/w/aZwcYHNlcnZpY2V8MURYeHl6WUFaUWdLTerSfgniRKoRgIPbfxxlbAGofYQNBd8WZZTEelJ0KavI?mode=couch'
```

As you can see, example.history[0].url tells you what was the URL that returned a 307 temporary redirect.

Comment: Try this and did not work, it seems like the URL gets updated in browser without redirect status_code, I've seen a lot with SPA doing this like twitter and facebook. for example go to a periscope user page and if user is live it updates URL with token `periscope.tv/username` --> `periscope.tv/username/token` still trying to figure how it works might have to go Javascript route on this problem :(

Comment: try a user profile and you will see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a user profile with a live streaming now.... I only opened the profile "example". Do you have more examples?

Comment: go to `https://www.periscope.tv/ChatwithDrPat` it is live now watch the url get changed once you enter the url

Comment: Mmh, I think I need an app for this - right? I opened the channel, but no video appeared.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to use urllib2 and override HTTPRedirectHandler's redirect_request() method. There's probably a more elegant way to do this with Requests, but I'm unfamiliar with the package.

```
import urllib2

class FindRedirect(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    def redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs, newurl):
        print('Sale has started!!')
        return urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.redirect_request(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs, newurl)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(FindRedirect)
opener.open('http://googel.com')
```